# HTTP request: End connection to proxy

Tags: sockets, http, request

I'm currently connected to a local proxy `127.0.0.1:5034` using a socket, and through it I send a connect request to another external proxy server by using:

```
CONNECT 192.168.1.2:5043 HTTP/1.1
Host:192.168.1.2
```

After that I receive The following message:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But the problem is after that, when I try to end my connection with the remote proxy by this:

```
Connection: close
```

it seems like even the local proxy `127.0.0.1:5034` is closed and causing a socket error, I've searched for some time to find a way to end just the connect request but can't seem to find it.

Is there a way to close the connection just for the remote proxy and keep the local proxy connection alive?

Comment: `Connection: close` isn't an HTTP command. It is a header in a request or response, and it means what happens *after* this request/response pair. If you're the client and you've sent a request and received a response you can now just close the socket. Everybody will understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible. By design, `CONNECT` transforms the HTTP/1.1 connection into a tunnel, and requests inside that tunnel are opaque to `127.0.0.1:5034`: it merely forwards bytes back and forth until the tunnel is closed. [RFC 7231 § 4.3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.6) says (emphasis mine):

> A tunnel is closed when a tunnel intermediary detects that either
> side has closed its connection: the intermediary MUST attempt to send
> any outstanding data that came from the closed side to the other
> side, **close both connections**, and then discard any remaining data
> left undelivered.